# How to display details from database to html template in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, jinja2

I am making a registration form with the help of [medium.com](https://medium.com/@himanshuxd/how-to-create-registration-login-webapp-with-django-2-0-fd33dc7a6c67). Admin display some information from database to html template using some syntax. But how to display **email, portfolio site** ?

Comment: What have you tried? What does your code look like?

Comment: We are going to need a lot more information than you have provided.

Comment: Please start with [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/intro/) instead of some random blog post that doesn't explain anything. If you haven't done the full Django tutorial, don't ask questions about Django on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Data from the db using a Manager and pass it into the template context like following.

Views

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        user = User.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'home.html', context={'users': user})
```

Template

```
{% for user in users %}
{{user.id}}
{{user.username}}
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: You forgot to close `context` in your view.  SO won't let me fix it for you since it's only 1 character.

Comment: You are displaying information of all users. How to display information for only authorised user. And I want to display some other information also on HTML template such as "email, portfolio site".

Comment: you can modify the `query` you put in, such as this `User.objects.filter(is_authorised=True)` this will give you a list of all authorised users. I am assuming `is_authorised` is a model field in your Model.